# Indefinite Integration involving partial fraction

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{11e^{2x} - 6}{ 25e^{24x} - 30e^{22x}+9e^{20x}}\mathrm dx$$

My work: Actually I haven't done anything except changing the denominator part into ${(5e^{12x}-3)}^2$ and then assuming $e^x = t$ and then the question becomes

$$\int \frac{11t^2 - 6}{{t^{21}(5t^2-3)^2}}\mathrm dt.$$

After that only way I know to proceed is by partial fraction method, but it will be much time taking for $t^{21}$.  Is there any other way to integrate?

Comment: I've taken the (extensive) liberty of formatting your post with MathJax. Please check to ensure the meaning is preserved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the denominator factors as $\mathrm{e}^{20x} \left( 5 \mathrm{e}^{2x} - 3 \right)^2$.  Then, taking $t = \mathrm{e}^{2x}$ is a little better (since every exponent has an even coefficient).

Comment: You can type this $ $ (11t^2-6)/(t^20(5t^2-3)^2)  $ $ on www.integral-calculator.com for detailed step by step working.

Comment: Yes, its correct Sean Roberson

Comment: Stephen, sometimes they show lengthier methods, like for this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Multiply and divide by $e^{40x}$ and then take $e^{40x}$ of denominator inside the whole square bracket. Then the derivative of entity in denominator will be present in numerator

Answer (score 2):

Start with $e^{2x}=\frac{1}{t}$, then $\frac{dt}{dx}=-2t$. So
$$\int \frac{11e^{2x} - 6}{ 25e^{24x} - 30e^{22x}+9e^{20x}}\, dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t^{10}(11-6t)}{9t^2-30t+25} \, dt=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{t^{10}(11-6t)}{(3t-5)^2} \, dt.$$
Now perform partial fractions as the denominator degree is only $2$.

Comment: Its still long Anurag

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Set $e^{2x}=t,$ and $dt=2e^{2x}dx,$ so $\frac{dt}{2t}=dx$ then we get

$$\int \frac{11t-6}{25t^{12}-30t^{11}+9t^{10}}dx=\int\frac{11t-6}{2t(t^{10})(25t^2-30t+9)}dt$$